# JAVA Intellij Coding

Tags: java

```
String marital = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you a single or married joint filer?");
while ((marital.length() >= 6) && (marital.length() <= 7)) {
    System.out.println("You are " + marital + " thank you.");
    if (marital.length() > 7) {
        break;
    }
}
```

im pretty new to Java so i was wondering how i could stop the while loop from printing more than one line. The objective is that the user will say single or married but i dont know how to only print it once

Comment: sorry i was trying to edit

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of what your loop is trying to do so you might want to explain the problem you're trying to solve.  The user should not have to guess what you are trying to accomplish.  E.g.  I'm trying to print out the 4th question in my list only once. ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `break;` after print, just like that, no `if` or anything. Right now you have your `break` inside `if`, that checks condition that will for sure fail, because if there was a possiblity that `marital.length > 7` then it wouldn't even enter this while loop, since you are making sure that it's length is 7 or lower. All this code is weird tho, you are probably doing all this to train/learn, but I suggest just doing this:

```
String marital = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you a single or married joint filer?");
if ((marital.length() == 6) || (marital.length() == 7)) {
    System.ou.tprintln("You are " + marital + " thank you.");
}
```

That will check if martital length is 6 OR 7 (you had something like that in your code, expressed in a convoluted way) and if yes then it's gonna print your sentence.